# Выражение "лично я"

Tags: орфоэпия

Является ли правильным выражение "лично я"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это просторечное выражение, но оно не является грамотным для русской речи. Или "лично", или "я".

Answer (score 1):

Я - это личное местоимение, поэтому  словосочетание "лично я " является плеоназмом. Это значит, что одно слово в данном словосочетании лишнее.